# Subset NetCDF file by Longitude and Depth and Calculate Mean

Tags: r, subset, mean, ncdf4

I am working with a NetCDF file in R using the ncdf4 library. I want to subset the file based on specific conditions. The file contains oceanographic data (temperature) with dimensions for longitude, latitude, depth, and time. My goal is to subset the data by longitude and depth, considering west (>= 37), south (< 37), shelf (<= 266.04314), and slope (above 266.04314). Additionally, I want to calculate the mean value of temperature based on each of these factors and based on time as well.
The file is from Copernicus (https://data.marine.copernicus.eu/product/GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_PHY_001_030/description)

I'm facing the challenge of handling a large dataset, and I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to subset the NetCDF file based on my conditions and calculate the mean temperature for each region (west shelf, south shelf, west slope, south slope) without having to load the entire dataset into a DataFrame.
Any  insights on optimizing this process would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(ncdf4)

# OPEN the NCD file
ncfname <- paste("path/Temp_data_1993-01-02.nc") # path of the file and file name
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)

# Names of the variables
names(ncin$var) # thetao

# Names of the dimensions
names(ncin$dim) # depth # latitude #longitude #time

# Get coordinates, time and depth variables
longitude <- ncin$dim[[3]]$vals
latitude <- ncin$dim[[2]]$vals
time <- ncin$dim[[4]]$vals
depth <- ncin$dim[[1]]$vals

# Get the time variable
time
nt <- dim(time)
nt # 2 days

# Get the time units
t_units <- ncatt_get(ncin, "time", "units")
t_units # its in hours since 1950-01-01

# convert time -- split the time units string into fields
t_ustr <- strsplit(t_units$value, " ")
t_dstr <- strsplit(unlist(t_ustr)[3], "-")
date <- ymd(t_dstr) + dhours(time)
date 

# Get the oceanographic variable
#sea_water_potential_temperature
T_array <- ncvar_get(ncin,ncin$var[[1]])
T_vector <- as.vector(T_array)

# ----- How I would subset it in a dataframe ----#
# Get all the variables into a dataframe
longitude <- as.matrix(longitude)
latitude <- as.matrix(latitude)
depth <- as.matrix(depth)

coords <- expand.grid(latitude, longitude, depth, date)

coords <- data.frame(coords)
data_fram <- cbind(coords, T_vector)

# Create bathymetric factor (slope and shelf)
data_fram$bath <- factor(ifelse(data_fram$depth <=266.04314, "shelf", "slope"))

# Create coast line factor (west and south)
data_fram$coast <- factor(ifelse(data_fram$longitude <=37, "south", "west"))

# Create the area factor (bathymetric + coast)
data_fram$area <- paste(data_fram$bath,"_",data_fram$coast)

# Extract the mean
data_mean_area <- aggregate(Temp ~ area * date, FUN = mean, data = data_fram)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a data.frame? If you want efficient use of memory you should work directly with the arrays you are extracting from the file

Comment: Yes, I don't want to do it on a data frame. However I am not sure how to do it directly on the NC file.

Comment: Hi Marta, what is your study area? There is not much ocean around the longitude of 37 E degrees (Black Sea? Red Sea?) where west of *and south of* make sense. Or is it perhaps Portugal, given that the south-west point of Portugal is at exactly 37 degrees N of *latitude*, with the Atlantic Ocean to the west and the Golfo de Cadiz to the south? You hyperlink a global file but it appears to me that you are using one of the regional data sets. Can you give the exact name of the data set?

Comment: Hi Patrick! My study area is the Portuguese coast. The subset data I've used is the following: cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083_P1D-m. I have extracted it following the tutorial (https://help.marine.copernicus.eu/en/articles/8638253-how-to-download-data-via-the-copernicus-marine-toolbox-in-r). My subsetted area in time and geometrical space is: # Time range
date_min = ymd(19930101) # start_date
date_max = ymd(19931231) # end_date

# Geographic area and depth level 
lon = list(-11., -6.)  # lon_min, lon_max
lat = list(35.5, 42.) # lat_min, lat_max
depth = list(0.494025 , 1684.284058)